# How that a row exists with specific values in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I've got a table looking like:

```
productId  uid  version
```

I just want to know if a row with specific values exists, I don't need any data returned.

How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE productId=210)
```

Comment: To see if the specific value exists in any rows. Did you read the question? :P

Answer (score 1):

A simple one is;

```
SELECT EXISTS (
  SELECT uid FROM my_table 
  WHERE product_id = <product id to check for>
    AND uid        = <uid to check for>
    AND version    = <version to check for>
) does_exist;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0ff62/3).

It will return 1 if the row exists, 0 if it doesn't.

You can also do it with `COUNT`;

```
SELECT COUNT(*) how_many_exist
FROM my_table 
WHERE product_id = <product id to check for>
  AND uid        = <uid to check for>
  AND version    = <version to check for>
```

...but this will most likely be slower, since `EXISTS` only needs to find a single row to return 1, while `COUNT` needs to do work on finding *all matching rows* (even if only one exists) to count them.

Comment: thanks for the sqlfiddle, never knew something like that existed!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM product_table where productId  =2
```

if the result is > 0 then product with id 2 exist otherwise doesn't